# pandas unicode decode error

Tags: python, pandas, unicode

I have a pandas dataframe,let's call it data.Data has one column.This column contains some formula like this:

```
0    apple + car * tree ÷ oil
1    apple / peach × dog
```

And i would like to replace every "÷" with "/","×"(this is not the letter "x"!!!) with "*".So i did something like this:

```
data.replace({"×":"*","÷":"/"})
```

but i got an Unicode decode error saying:

```
UnicodeDecodeError:'ascii' codec can't decode byte Oxc3
```

yet,if do something like this:

```
data[column_name] = data[column_name].apply(lambda x:x.replace(u"×","*"))
data[column_name] = data[column_name].apply(lambda x:x.replace(u"÷","/"))
```

everything is fine.So i tried this:

```
data.replace({u"×":"*",u"÷":"/"})
```

now python won't give me any error,but no thing has happened to my formula.So do i have to write two lines of code instead of one?What if i have even more characters to replace?

Comment: [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html#pandas.DataFrame.replace) does not replace in place by default, you need to pass `inplace=True`, you can also pass a dict of the values to lookup as the keys, with the values to replace as the dict values

Comment: i tried 'df.replace({u"×":"*"},inplace=True)',but still no change has appied to my dataframe.